# Why doesn't "strip" remove these debug symbols?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

I have a simple assembly file `main.s` which contains:

`mysymbol1=1234`

I assemble it into an object file using the following command:

`$ arm-none-eabi-as main.s -o main.o`

Now I check the symbol table

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -t main.o

main.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
000004d2 l       *ABS*  00000000 mysymbol1
00000000 l    d  .ARM.attributes    00000000 .ARM.attributes
```

I note that the `d` indicates that there are debug symbols included so I run:

`$ arm-none-eabi-strip --strip-debug main.o`

Re-running objdump shows that the debug symbols have not been removed, although they have been reordered:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -t main.o

main.o:     file format elf32-littlearm

SYMBOL TABLE:
000004d2 l       *ABS*  00000000 mysymbol1
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .ARM.attributes    00000000 .ARM.attributes
```

Why aren't the debug symbols removed?

Comment: These symbols indicate the names of the sections. That's why `strip` won't get rid of them. They are not debugging symbols.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why is the `d` bit flag is set then?

Comment: I don't know the GNU binutils well enough to answer this question.

Comment: Presumably the kernel (and by extension the debugger) needs to know where the code (.text) and data (.data .bss) sections are located so they are not stripped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text`, `.data` and `.bss` are not debug symbols - they are file segments which are used by kernel to properly execute it. `mysymbol1` comes from static symbol table and thus is not part of debuginfo so it's not stripped under `--strip-debug` either.

Comment: Thanks. BTW I think you mean `mysymbol1` and yes, it's not a debug symbol so wouldn't be stripped.

Comment: @donturner Ah, fixed.